# How to order rows randomly but keep groups together?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

My table looks like this:

```
GroupID INT NOT NULL
SomeValue INT NOT NULL
```

I'd like to keep rows with the same `GroupID` together in the result set. The groups themselves should be ordered randomly, though. `SomeValue` is supposed to be the secondary sort criterion. Like this:

```
GroupID, SomeValue
13, 1
13, 2
7, 1
7, 2
11, 1
11, 2
...
```

`ORDER BY GroupID, SomeValue` does not order groups randomly. `ORDERBY NEWID()` is totally random. `ORDER BY SomeHash(GroupID), SomeValue` comes to mind but I need a new random order each time.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need a random order for the `GroupID` values, so first get these distinct values and a random number for each, in a derived table:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tablename AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT GroupID, 
             NEWID() AS rnd   -- or another random function
      FROM tablename
      GROUP BY GroupID
    ) AS r
    ON r.GroupID = t.GroupID 
ORDER BY 
    r.rnd, 
    t.SomeValue ;
```

If you already have a `Groups` table which holds the `GroupID` values, you can replace that `FROM tablename GROUP BY GroupID` with `FROM Groups`.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use (Thanks to ypercubeᵀᴹ for the fix)

```
SELECT GroupID,
       SomeValue
FROM   tablename
ORDER  BY FIRST_VALUE(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY GroupID),
          GroupID, --Just in case 2 groups get the same random number
          SomeValue;
```

[Online demo](http://rextester.com/EEC78286)